# Changing text of textbox on another form

Tags: c#, .net, string, text, textbox

Ok so

i have 2 form lets call them **main** and **second** forms

On **main** there is nothing but a textbox(lets call it **T1**) which is *PUBLIC* so it supposed to be reachable from any form.

On **second** there is nothing but a textbox(**T2**) which is public, and a button(pub)(call it **B**)

On the codes, there is nothing in **main**

On the codes of  **second** there is

```
public string s1
```

and in codes of button **B**:

```
s1 = T2.Text;
MAIN mainredirect = new MAIN();
MAIN.T1.Text = s1;
```

and thats it. what i am doing wrong?

*p.s: there is no error that shown by vs, so its not syntax error*

Comment: Your question is missing some very important required information, i.e. what you expected to happen and what actually happened. As it is now, I can't figure out the problem you want help with.

Comment: What actually happened: nothing

Comment: what did i wanted: transfer string of t2 to t1

Comment: Call mainredirect.Show(), like @archer proposed.  Thinking about what you see is *very* important to understand object oriented programming.

Comment: I dont use it because second form is opened by showdialog from main form, and when user clicks B button it closes. main form is always there.

Comment: OH CRAP! i guess i misunderstand you, that code worked! however im bringing second form with showdialog, and well main form have more info than just a textbox. how can i just transfer it without opening it agani ?

Comment: btw i tried refresh but didnt help

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The question is unclear, and I understood the comments even less. Seems like I'm not the only one who is unable to help because they don't know what you're trying to do. Consider editing your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand what you trying to achieve, but probably you forget to simply `Show()` created form.

**EDIT:**

Readed your comments. As i understand your **main** form opens **second** form like a dialog and you want to get entered value from it.

Code for your main form will be:

```
private void callSecondFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SecondForm second = new SecondForm();
    second.ShowDialog();
    mainFormTextBox.Text = second.Result;
}
```

For your second form:

```
public string Result = string.Empty;

private void secondFormCloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Result = secondFormTextBox.Text;
    Close();
}
```

**callSecondFormButton** - button on the main form that calls your second form;
**mainFormTextBox** - text box on your main form;
**SecondForm** - your second form that will be called from main;
**Result** - public field of second form for retrieving result of entering text;
**secondFormCloseButton** - button on the second form that will update Result and close dialog.

In the main form need first to create second form instance and show form. After executing `ShowDialog` main form will *wait* for closing opened form. After closing it will retrieve resulted text.

Answer (score 0):

Is this WinForms? It's a little hard to tell what you are trying to do. Have you stepped through with a debugger? Is the string getting set? How are you confirming it is not? Is it because the form is not yet loaded?

You are showing only snippets. It should be very easy for you to further isolate this using the debugger.